# Knockout nested objects and parentheses

Tags: knockout.js

Few things I don't get.
According to KO documentation (and many posts here on SO), parentheses should be used when querying and writing observables. But when binding sub-properties it seems to me that it doesn't matter if you use parentheses or not.

```
<span data-bind="text: selectedMessage() && selectedMessage().message().subject()"></span>
<span data-bind="text: selectedMessage() && selectedMessage().message().subject"></span>
```

= both return correct value.

Can anyone explain to me why this is?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/viktorb/DKg74/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the binding value is an observable, KO "unwraps" it for you, so you don't have to unwrap it yourself with the parentheses (or a call to ko.utils.unwrapObservable).

In your 2nd example the binding value is: `selectedMessage() && selectedMessage().message().subject`. When this expression evaluates to the `subject` property, KO sees that the evaluated value is an observable, and so it unwraps it for you. (Internally this is probably just a call to ko.utils.unwrapObservable).

But, since the expression *doesn't* evaluate to the `message` property, which I'm assuming is also an observable, the parentheses for accessing that property are necessary (e.g. `selectedMessage().message.subject` wouldn't work).

Answer (score 4):

Like the documentation says:

> The whole point of observables is that they can be observed, i.e., other code can say that it wants to be notified of changes. That’s what many of KO’s built-in bindings do internally. So, when you wrote data-bind="text: personName", the text binding registered itself to be notified when personName changes (assuming it’s an observable value, which it is now).

It's about being `observable` or not.

See the **Reading and writing observables** at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html for more information.

I've modified your fiddle a bit where you can see the difference with and without the parentheses: http://jsfiddle.net/DKg74/1/