# What is the different in knockout data_bind

Tags: knockout.js

What's the different between having `()` and not having `()`?

Like:

```
data-bind="text: firstName"
data-bind="text: firstName()"
```

In my viewModel:

```
this.firstName = ko.observable("Ben");
```

Both the `data-bind` can work. So what is the different?

Answer (score 1):

There are similar questions that have been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13444787/1287183).

The gist is that when using `text: firstName`, you're passing the observable to the `text` binding, and when using `text: firstName()`, you're passing the value of the observable to the binding. In both cases, the binding will work the same, because it's a one-way binding, and most bindings are set up to use either an observable or plain value. If, however, you are using a two-way binding such as `value`, you'll need to use the first format so that the binding can write back to the observable.

Answer (score 0):

An observable without the parentheses is the observable itself. With the parentheses, it is the contents (the value the observable holds). In most cases, you can use either/or, but for two-way binding (`value` or `checked`), you need to be able to assign to the observable, so you need to *not* have the parentheses. If you are going to make an expression, on the other hand, you need the contents. For example: `!someBoolean()`