# KnockoutJS Databinds Returning Empty String While Calling Returns Value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

So let's say I've got a `data-bind`:

```
<p data-bind="text: toClicked.title">This should be replaced.</p>
```

And I've got my `ko.observable()`:

```
toClicked : ko.observable({})
```

Which is then filled up based on a click on another set of arrays, with data similar to this:

```
markers : ko.observableArray([
    { title: 'Title', lat: 10, lng: -10, content: 'This is the relevant content' },
    // more objects in array
])
```

If I then call this observable in the console like `toClicked().title`, I'd return `Title`. If I simply call `toClicked();`, I get the following response:

`Object { title: "Title", lat: 10, lng: -10, content: "This is the relevant content" }`

But, inside the data-bind above, we overwrite the text inside the paragraph with nothing.

Is there something I'm missing here to make sure it's binding correctly? All other observables/observableArrays are working without a problem so I know it's something with how the binding is handling the information. Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

As a side note, I have tried `$root.toClicked.title` and `$parent.toClicked.title`, no joy.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question. In the console, you used `toClicked().title`, but in your markup you did `data-bind="text: toClicked.title"`. You can leave parentheses off when you're using a plain observable, but when it is an expression, the parentheses are required. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13444787/392102).

Do `data-bind="text: toClicked().title"`

The snippet below illustrates the difference.

```js
vm = {
  toClicked: ko.observable({}),
  markers: ko.observableArray([{
    title: 'Title',
    lat: 10,
    lng: -10,
    content: 'This is the relevant content'
  }]),
  setClicked: function () {
    vm.toClicked(vm.markers()[0]);
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>First: <p data-bind="text: toClicked.title">This should be replaced.</p></div>
<div>Second: <p data-bind="text: toClicked().title">This should be replaced.</p></div>
<button data-bind="click:setClicked">Set it</button>
```

Comment: With knockoutJS, you don't need to add the parens to call the observable iirc. Added in the parens and I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: You need to add the parens if you want to look at the contents.

Comment: I've added a snippet to my answer. Maybe it will help you find what else isn't right.